# Обновление таблицы путём поиска родительских значений полей в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Как решить такую задачу? (аналог поиска полного пути хлебных крошек через id_родителя)

Есть таблица T1 (например таблица категорий):

```
id | id_product | name | id_parent | name_parent | tree |

---------------------------------------------------------

1  | n1 | name1 | 0-0-0-0 | | |

2  | n2 | name2 | n1 | | |

3  | n3 | name3 | n2 | | |

4  | n4 | name4 | n3 | | |

5  | n5 | name5 | 0-0-0-0 | | |
```

Требуется обновить поле **tree** для каждой записи **все названия категорий** с учётом найденного id_родителя (конкатенация поля **name** - аля хлебные крошки):

должно вывести:

`1  | n1 | name1 | 0-0-0-0 | |name1|` - так как родитель с таким id не найден в tree пишется лишь собственное имя.

`2  | n2 | name2 | n1 |name1 |name1,name2 |` - родитель найден, запись в поле tree

`3  | n3 | name3 | n2 |name2 |name1,name2,name3 |` - родитель найден, запись в поле tree = tree родителя + своё имя

`4  | n4 | name4 | n3 |name3 |name1,name2,name3,name4 |` - родитель найден, запись в поле tree = tree родителя + своё имя

`5  | n5 | name5 | 0-0-0-0 | |name5 |` - так как родитель с таким id не найден в tree пишется лишь собственное имя

Можно в несколько запросов.
Пока получается обновить лишь:

1) случай когда id не найдет - в tree присвоить поле name

2) в tree удается записать лишь конкатенацию: name_parent+name но не удается записать конкатенацию tree (из найденной parent записи) + name текущей.

Comment: Что такое `0-0-0-0`, если нет parent записи, почему там не NULL ?

Answer (score 0):

Как то так:

```
update T1 O
  join (
    select id_product, path
      from (
        select id_product, N,
               @id:=if(@cid=id_product,@id,id_product),
               @cname:=if(@cid=id_product,@cname,name),
               @cid:=id_product,
               @id:=(select id_parent from T1 B where B.id_product=@id),
               @cname:=concat(coalesce((select concat(name,',') from T1 B where B.id_product=@id),''),@cname) path
          from T1 A,
               (select @n:=@n+1 N from T1,(select @n:=0) X limit 3) curs,
               (select @cid:='',@id:='',@cname:='') X
         order by id_product
      ) C
     where N=3
  ) N
    on O.id_product=N.id_product
   set tree=N.path
```

Число 3 в `limit` и в `N=3` заменить на максимальный встречающийся уровень вложенности. В дальнейшем лучше сделать триггер на добавление/изменение записей который будет брать `tree` из родительской записи, добавлять собственный name и заносить в NEW.tree. И подумать нельзя ли заменить MySQL на какой нибудь postgresql, потому что работа с деревьями на MySQL всегда выливается вот в такое извращение с переменными.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Завтра попробую обкатать ваш вариант. В (select @n:=@n+1 N from T1,(select @n:=0) X limit 3)  цыфра 3 это тоже самое ограничение что и N=3? (глубина рекурсии?)

Comment: @Артём да, то же самое. собственно этот подзапрос генерит нужное для обхода вглубь количество строк и по мере прохода этих строк алгоритм углубляется и на каждой строке дает +1 имя. На последней стадии оставляются только строки максимальной глубины, где уже сформирована полная цепочка имен